# Cannot compile Python package on Windows

Tags: python, c++, c, windows, gcc

Trying to install a compiled Python package on a 64-bit Windows machine using MinGW compiler. The same install succeeded on my 32-bit machine but failed on two different 64-bit machines:
`C:\Python\Scripts>` `pip install python-Levenshtein`

> C:\Python\libs/python33.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
>      collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Trying from a cloned copy:
`$ python setup.py build`

> C:\Python\libs/python33.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
>     collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Running the build command by itself:

`$ gcc.exe -shared -s 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\levenshtein\_levenshtein.o' 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\levenshtein\_levenshtein.def' -LC:'\Python\libs' -LC:'\Python\PCbuild\amd64' -lpython33 -lmsvcr100 -o 'build\lib.win-amd64-3.3\Levenshtein\_levenshtein.pyd'`

> C:\Python\libs/python33.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

`$ file 'C:\Python\libs/python33.lib'`

> C:\Python\libs/python33.lib: current ar archive

Thank you
- Muposat

Comment: I guess you have a 32/64 bit mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Not helpful, I know, but this is another reason why I moved to Linux. It is as easy as `sudo apt-get install python-levenshtein` and this is guaranteed to work in just one line

Comment: Is the Python you have installed a 64-bit Python or 32-bit? Because you may not be able to install a 32-bit package against a 64-bit Python

Comment: @Mike Driscoll: The Python installed is most definitely 64 bit. The package should not be tied to the machine architecture because isn't that the point behind compiling it instead of distributing a binary?